# using findIndex to check array of elements existed in array of objects - typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to check from array of properties which are present in array of objects and which are not.

My object is like this:

```js
var tempObj=[{id: '1', color: 'red, blue, green', age: 27},{id: '2', color: 'black, orange, yellow', age: 75}];
var tempColor = ['red', 'yellow', 'white'];
```

Here tempColor array contains three elements and I need to check these elements present in tempObj. Here in tempObj color property values are comma suppurated, so I am confusing here.
Basically for single element check i used to do like this

```js
var eleExists= this.tempObj.findIndex(obj => obj.age === 27) >= 0;
```

But for array elements to check with comma suppurated values don't have idea to check, so seeking for some help or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const data = [
    {id: '1', color: 'red, blue, green', age: 27},
    {id: '2', color: 'black, orange, yellow', age: 75},
  ]

  const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white']

  function getNeverUsedColors(colors, data) {
    return colors.filter(color => !data.some(obj => obj.color.split(', ').includes(color)))
  }

  console.log(getNeverUsedColors(colors, data))
  // returns ['white']
```

Comment: Here includes we may not use i think, If some other word contains red like tomotored, in this scenario conflicts may come right?

Comment: @Roy I updated the answer with solution that should fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your time..but with above solution we cant find right which are existed and which are not?

Comment: @Roy it depends on what format you need to get the checking result e.g. dictionary `{ [id]: boolean }`, or maybe an array of booleans, list of existed-only ids etc.

Comment: @Roy please specify the desired result.

Comment: Yeah here I am expecting like which are not existed..in this case White is the desired result. As red and yellow are existed in tempObj.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213185/discussion-between-kotofenum-and-roy).